# Перезагрузка ModalViewController в Xcode

Tags: xcode, objective-c, view

Всем привет!
У меня есть `MVC`, который открывается при нажатии на кнопку. В данном `MVC` (`scrollView+pageControl+textView`) находится "Избранное"(данные берутся из `plist`-файла) моего приложения. Я хотел бы реализовать возможность удаления. Хотел бы сделать так: удаляю из `plist`'a (сделал), а потом полностью перезагружаю `View`, то есть как-будто я закрыл его и снова открыл. Как это сделать (`setNeedsDisplay`, `reloadInputViews` и `removeFromSuperview` не предлагать)?

Как вариант:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ModalViewName"];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Только данный код открывает новый `MVC`, а не перезагружает. Спасибо.

Comment: А в чем данные отображаются из плиста? Как вариант заюзать таблицу, и там уже все просто.

Comment: С таблицей это да. Но у меня они в UITextView, которые я потом скроллю.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно заново загрузить данные из .plist и задать новые значения TextField. Зачем перезагружать целый ViewController, когда можно изменить пару элементов?